# get records from now till future

Tags: laravel

I want get all records that date alarm is now till future
I dont need records that have date alarm is in past

this is my Code:

```
 $future=Carbon::now();
 $time=$future->addMonth();
 $records = document_date::where('date_alarm',$future)->whereHas('document')->with([
     'document' => function ($query) {
          $query->with([
              'userClients' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('type', 4)->with(['users']);
               }
           ]);
       }
   ])->orderBy('date', 'DESc')->get();
```

how can I do it?

Comment: did you try `where('date_alarm', '>=' , $future)` ?

Comment: use `whereBetween( 'date_alarm' [$now , $future] )`   instead of where

Answer (score 0):

use whereBetween( 'date_alarm' [$now , $future] ) instead of where

```
     $now=Carbon::now();
     $future=$now->addMonth();
 $records = document_date::whereBetween('date_alarm' [$now , $future])->whereHas('document')->with([
     'document' => function ($query) {
          $query->with([
              'userClients' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('type', 4)->with(['users']);
               }
           ]);
       }
   ])->orderBy('date', 'DESc')->get();
```